# Loading Data into UIPIckerView?

Tags: ios, delegates, datasource, uipickerview

I'm trying to build an app which works alongside a database of `PDF's`. What I need is for the app to look at all of the files (PDF's) which are stored and to pull the certain files out, check this against the database and then show a list of which PDF's are available on a `UIPicker`.

My first step would be that the app checks the files and creates a picker wheel which has been populated with the countries for which there is data in the directory.

To make this work I have created a standard format for the file names: 'Country-Airfield-Plate Name-Date.pdf', e.g. “UK-London Heathrow-ILS DME NDB 27-100214.pdf”. I've split this filename first at the full stop to get two strings: 'UK-London Heathrow-ILS DME NDB 27’ and ‘pdf’, and then we split the title at the hyphens to get ‘UK’, ‘London Heathrow’ and ‘ILS DME NDB 27’.

The app will check the first string for the country information, then the second for the airfield and will then display a list of the third strings for the appropriate airfield.

How can I First Fetch the data from database for a particular field for eg. country make a `NSArray` form that data and load that `NSArray` to `UIPickerView`, then use that array in `UIPickerView` `Delegate` and `Datasource` methods?

Comment: Are you working with Core Data? If so you can use NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor to your NSFetchRequest and get your results the way you want it.

Comment: Im working with a range of different PDF Documents (each document has a different name ie UK-London Heathrow-ILS DME NDB 27-100214.pdf) I need the app to search through the PDFs and able to load the correct ones on the UIPickerView accordingly. For example it would look through the PDF's take the first instance (country) then list the Countries on the UIPickerView. Once the user has selected the Country it would take the second instance (county) and create a UIPickerView of counties just for the desired country though that had been previously selected.

Comment: Can someone shed some more light on how to tackle this? I have had a look into NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor to your NSFetchRequest cant seem to get my head around how it would fetch the data from the PDF. Has anyone got an example of how the process can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any web service going and you are handling the documents yourself. You can hardcode a .plist file and put it on your website, download this small plist file every time the app opens, encrypt and save it to your documents directory.

The plist is basically a `NSDictionary` with objects and keys.
So your plist structure would look like this:

```
{
    Countries =     (
                {
            Airfields =             (
                                {
                    Code = JNB;
                    Plates =                     (
                                                {
                            Title = "Plate 1";
                            URL = "http://www.airport.com/za/airfield/plate1/document.pdf";
                        }
                    );
                    Title = "OR Tambo";
                }
            );
            Title = "South Africa";
        }
    );
}
```

The above example only holds 1 object in each array in your case it would be more.

Then use the following `UIPickerView` delegate assuming button.tag is called to change pickerview.tag and display correct array for the pickerview:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [[self returnCorrectArrayForButton:pickerView.tag] count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[[self returnCorrectArrayForButton:pickerView.tag] objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Title"];
}

// Handle these errors where user can click on any button. Airfields will be empty if no country selected. Plates will be empty when no Airfields selected. After loading all arrays, pressing random buttons might give wrong information.

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {

        _airfieldArray = [[_countryArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Airfields"];
        [_countryButton setTitle:[[_countryArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else if (pickerView.tag == 2) {

        _plateArray = [[_airfieldArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Plates"];
        [_airfieldButton setTitle:[[_airfieldArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else if (pickerView.tag == 3) {

        // Show PDF in webview for selected plate
        [_plateButton setTitle:[[_plateArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSString *urlString = [[_plateArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"URL"];
        NSLog(@"Selected Plate PDF URL : %@", urlString);
    }
}

- (NSArray *)returnCorrectArrayForButton:(NSUInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Return Countries array
        return _countryArray;

    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        // Return Airfield array
        return _airfieldArray;

    } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
        // Return Plates array
        return _plateArray;
    }
    return nil;
}
```